# Figuring out a K'zayit by weight/volume of ingredients

Tags: shiurim-measurements, bread

In [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/219/is-there-a-minimum-amount-of-dough-to-separate-challah-without-a-bracha), I learned that one measures the amount of flour used to determine whether challah separation is necessary. [Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6923/603) I learned that there is a difference of opinion between (some) Sefardim and Ashkenazim whether a K'zayit is measured by weight or volume.

My question now is, can one use the amount of ingredients in a recipe to calculate how much of the prepared food is a K'zayit? This would be useful when determining how much is needed to eat to make a [blessing over the hand washing](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbos7_29.htm), and say the Grace After Meals.

Here's an example which focuses on the volume, but the same question would apply to weight if the igredients were weighed instead of measured by volume. For the sake of simplicity we'll assume that all parts get distributed equally:

I adapted [this recipe](http://www.ehow.com/how_5265248_make-excellent-tortillas-scratch.html) to make 8 equal size flour tortillas. Here is the recipe I used. I used [this website](http://www.calculateme.com/Volume/Cups/ToCubicCentimeters.htm) to convert the cups to cubic centimeters, and put the number in parenthesis:

- 2 cups of flour (**473.1764725** Cubic Centimeters)
- a dash of baking powder
- 1/2 a cup of oil (**118.29411812499998** Cubic Centimeters)
- 3/4 of a cup of water (**177.4411771875** Cubic Centimeters)

According to [this article](http://www.vbm-torah.org/pesach/pes62-yr.htm), R' Avraham Chaim Na'eh holds that the stricter definition of a K'zayit is **27 cubic centimeters**, while the Chazon Ish holds that it is **47.5 cubic centimeters**.

So my question now is, can I add up all the cubic centimeters used in the recipe, divide by 8 and use that information to determine how much of the tortilla is a K'zayit? If I add it all up, the recipe calls for a total of **768.911768** cubic centimeters. This means that each tortilla uses **[96.113971](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=473.1764725/8&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#hl=en&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&sclient=psy-ab&q=%28473.1764725%2b118.29411812499998%2b177.4411771875%29/8&oq=%28473.1764725%2b118.29411812499998%2b177.4411771875%29/8&aq=f&aqi=h1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=5152l16815l2l18202l4l4l0l0l0l0l238l920l2-4l4l0&gs_l=serp.3..19.5152l16815l2l18203l4l4l0l0l0l0l238l920l2-4l4l0.frgbld.&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=7dfa92a487c36218&biw=1280&bih=615)** cubic centimeters of ingredients.

Can I therefore say that one tortilla is 2 K'zaytim according to the Chazon Ish, and 3.5 K'zaytim according to R' Avraham Chaim Na'eh? Is this a valid halachic way to determine the volume of a food item, or are there other factors that must be taken into account?

Comment: How much water evaporates?

Comment: Kezayit for what purpose? For some things the halacha may look at the final size while for others it may only matter the amount of flour that went in. It depends on the application.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill: My guess is almost none. I mix the dough and then bake it on a girdle for about 1 minute on each side. I don't kno w how much of the water evaporates, however.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill: I do not have a food scale. I have this recipe, and I'm trying to figure out how much I need to eat to say grace after meals (K'zayit), and how much I need to eat to say Al Netilat Yadayim (K'Beitza).

Comment: @DoubleAA: For birchat hamazon and blessing on hand washing.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill, would a scale help? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6920

Comment: Menachem, you may wish to edit into the question your addressing of DoubleAA's point.

Comment: This could be a simple thing to test. Measure ingredients, cook food, weigh food, see if weight is the same.

Comment: You have to account for the fact that liquid evaporates. Otherwise you could have things that are clearly smaller than an olive but are more than a kezayit.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Is there a way to calculate how much liquid evaporates? Interestingly, even the flour alone is more than a K'zayit: 473.1764725/8 = 59.1470591

Comment: @Menachem _a priori_, there are a number of [factors to consider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporation#Factors_influencing_the_rate_of_evaporation). _a posteriori_: final volume - initial volume = change in volume.

Answer (score 1):

I propose that that is *not* a valid method to measure volume for purposes of *b'racha acharona* for foods generally, though I can't speak to its applicability to tortillas specifically. Here's a counterexample to show its inapplicability in general: coffee, brewed in a stovetop percolator. Put whatever quantity of coffee grounds and water in the percolator, turn on the gas, and wait. The coffee (and grounds) that come out will be considerably less than what went in. Yet search as you might on Google, there are many who discuss how much coffee must be drunk to require a *b'racha acharona*, but no one seems to take into account the amount of water put into the percolator: they all measure the amount actually drunk. This is not a great proof (*lo rainu eno r'aya*), but it's somewhat indicative.

Comment: This is basically what I said in [this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15210/figuring-out-a-kzayit-by-weight-volume-of-ingredients/15243#comment29741_15210) above.

Comment: @DoubleAA, and, before you, [Shmuel Brill](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15210/figuring-out-a-kzayit-by-weight-volume-of-ingredients/15243#comment29593_15210). But I gave a concrete example of coffee.

Comment: Bemchillat kevod Shmuel Brill, he didn't give a svara. I'm not sure how much more conclusive your discussion about coffee is compared to the general problem of things having different shiurim than they have which could have infinite ridiculous nafka minas. What you have _not_ dealt with is [Menachem's comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15210/figuring-out-a-kzayit-by-weight-volume-of-ingredients/15243#comment29744_15210) about the flour itself being more than a kezayit per tortilla.

Comment: _no one seems to take into account the amount of water put into the percolator: they all measure the amount actually drunk._ -- but that's because how much liquid there is has no bearing on whether you need to make a blessing or not. The only factor is how much you drank. A better parallel would be to ask if the amount of water put in to the percolator could be used to determine if there was a revi'is of coffee.

Comment: @Menachem, but the question was [about](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15210/figuring-out-a-kzayit-by-weight-volume-of-ingredients/15243#comment29611_15210) _b'racha acharona_, and that's what I find a lot of discussion about (for coffee).

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be mixing up three different issues.

1. How much of a raw ingredient is needed to "tithe" (take halah, trumah or meiser)
2. How much food needs to be eaten for a certain bracha.
3. How to measure or decide if the amount of food needed fulfills the halachic requirements.

While issue 3 is a matter of great halachic debate, issues 1 and 2 are not debated at all.
Issue 1 has straight forward "amounts" in the halacha.  Whether or not you fulfill those amounts is dedpendant on issue 3.
Issue 2 however is the main question that you ask here, and all agree that to figure out if you need to make certain brachot, the question is how much went into your mouth.
The only way to figure out how many beitzot or kzayit are needed for a bracha is to measure the food that you have eaten.  If you know for certain how the food shrinks or grows based on your ingredients, then perhaps you could figure it out from ingredients alone, but that seems much more difficult than just measuring and weighing a single tortilla and figuring out it's size and weight.