# Different flour:oil ratios in the mincha sacrifices -- how did the dough stay together?

Tags: food, oil, mincha-meal-offering

If I understand correctly, different animal sacrifices had different amounts of flour & oil to be brought with them:

Measured in (*eiphas* of flour / *hins* of oil):

- bull: 0.6
- ram: 0.6
- sheep: 0.4

Has anyone ever checked if these different ratios still hold together?

Comment: Do you have any reason to assume not? It sounds pretty oily to me.

Comment: why are you assuming that the flour and oil was mixed together into a dough? The recipe mentioned in this question says: _Pour 2 cups of all-purpose flour and 1/8 tsp. of baking powder in a large bowl. Blend the ingredients with your hands. Add 1/3 cup of ... vegetable shortening, if desired. Knead the mixture until you have a crumbly texture._ -- http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15210/figuring-out-a-kzayit-by-weight-volume-of-ingredients -- perhaps the mincha offering was the same.

Comment: Well, efah is 72 log, and hin is 12 log, so it's 18:5 flour to oil for the thicker, assuming the log are equal (?). Figure like 3-plus cups flour to one cup oil. Sounds reasonable, batter-y.

Comment: Let's see what our good friends over here think: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/22456/8291

Comment: Here's a 3:1 AP flour/canola mixture. I forgot to use olive oil. http://www.flickr.com/photos/54284792@N02/6856560218/

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, as Menachem commented, it's not necessary to assume that they were made into a dough. No kometz (handful) was taken from such menachos (see Rambam, [Hil. Pesulei Hamukdashin 18:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=8&hilchos=47&perek=18&halocha=8&hilite=)), so it may not have mattered much whether it could hold together as a solid. (With private menachos, on the other hand, the ratio was 1/10 eifah flour (7.2 log) to 1 log oil, which would probably make for a pretty stiff dough.)

There is also the case where the kometz of a regular minchah gets mixed up with a minchas nesachim ([Menachos 22a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=22&format=pdf)), where R. Yehudah points out that "they absorb [oil] from each other" - and Rashi there (ד"ה והן בולעות) notes that it's not really "each other," rather that the kometz will absorb oil from the minchas nesachim. This also suggests that the latter is more crumbly (or perhaps, as yitznewton said, batter-y), otherwise the oil wouldn't be wicked up out of it so easily.