# Why are oil to flour ratios different for different animals?

Tags: korban

[Bamidbar 15:4-10](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=186) relates the menachot and nesachim for each animal:

1. Sheep: 1 issaron of flour, 1/4 hin of oil (and 1/4 hin of wine)
2. Ram: 2 issarons of flour, 1/3 hin of oil (and 1/3 hin of wine)
3. Bull: 3 issarons of flour, 1/2 hin of oil (and 1/2 hin of wine)

I.e.,

- for both *bull* and *ram*, "oiliness" is **1/6** hin per issaron,
- while for *sheep* the "oiliness" is **1/4** hin per issaron.

IOW, the minchah for a sheep is 50% more oily (fatter/richer/tastier?).

**Why do sheep require a different oil/flour ratio?**

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15272/759

Comment: is it because a bull is bigger than a ram which is bigger than a sheep? do your equations show that the bigger the animal, it gets more oil and flour? (I understand your question is why, but is my hereby observation correct?)

Comment: @ninamag: no, first, bull is bigger than ram but has the same oiliness, second, why would an absolute size affect a relative oiliness?

Comment: Seemingly this is just a coincidence from the Law of Very Small Numbers

Comment: @DoubleAA do you mean [Strong Law of Small Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers)?