# How can chala be taken from baked bread?

Tags: food, bread, separating-challah

I understand that i can take off chala from baked bread. How is this done?

Why is there no problem that the taste of the bread (before chala was taken) will be in the oven tray? The bread, before chala was taken, was not kosher, so isn't the tray not kosher now, having absorbed the taste of the not kosher bread?

Related:
[Is there a minimum amount of dough to separate challah without a bracha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/219/is-there-a-minimum-amount-of-dough-to-separate-challah-without-a-bracha/220#220)

Answer (score 4):

*Challah* in *chutz la'aretz* may be taken after (most of) the bread has been eaten, since it is only *mid'rabonon* (*[Shulchan Aruch YD 323:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.323.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)*). However, one must leave over a little more than the *shiur challah* which he will separate, in order that there should be something leftover from which to separate it (*[Rema ibid](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.323.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)*).

> Why is there no problem that the taste of the bread (before chala was taken) will be in the oven tray?

Rema ([YD 324:12](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.324.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), quoting the [*Beis Yosef s.v. מצאתי*](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6434)) writes:

> הָאוֹפֶה פַּשְׁטִידָ''א מֵעִסָּה שֶׁלֹּא הֻרְמָה חַלָּתָהּ, וּבְתוֹכוֹ בָּשָׂר, מֻתָּר לְהַפְרִישׁ מֵעִסָּה אַחֶרֶת הַחַיֶּבֶת בְּחַלָּה עַל זוֹ
>  **וְנִפְטַר גַּם כֵּן טַעַם הָעִסָּה הַנִּכְנָס בַּבָּשָׂר**

Thus, separating *challah* at a later point exempts any absorbed taste from the dough.

(*credit: [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa)*)